# How to automate Acumatica UI testing with Selenium

Tags: acumatica

Is there a way to use Selenium to do UI test automations.  All Acumatica UI elements don't have ID's so Selenium will not find elements when going through the UI tests.  Do we have a way to automate UI testing for Acumatica using Selenium?

Answer (score 0):

There is a TestSDK for Acumatica. Sergey Marenich has a good intro article found here:
[Acumatica Test Framework](http://asiablog.acumatica.com/2016/10/acumatica-test-framework.html)